# Estimate ZPL Render And Print Times

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl

I am working on a set of ZPL validation routines which parse arbitrary ZPL files, sanitize them, edit certain key commands (label length, print speeds, etc), and extract some useful information.

Since this printer is generating labels for a free-running shipping line I really need to know how long it's going to take from the moment I send the ZPL file to the printer until I'll be ready to apply the label.  It is clear that the print time is directly linked to the label length and print speeds, but the label render time (conversion of ZPL into ready to print image in printer memory) is less obvious.

Since I'm printing label contents provided by numerous third parties, I can't simply measure the time for the labels.  I've asked Zebra and gotten no guidance, so I'm wondering if anyone has an idea of how to estimate the render time?  Am I stuck trying to estimate the processing time of every individual ZPL command?

Comment: Did you find anything relevant here?

Comment: No.  Zebra basically said there's no easy solution to this as it depends too much on the internal settings of each printer model.  It is possible to create a reasonable upper bound estimate for most command types, so you can create a fair estimate of worst case times, which was sufficient for me.  Sorry I can't provide more specifics

Answer (score 0):

My experience over the last couple of years working with differnt zebra printers (Z4M, ZM400, GK420t) is, that the label that is send to the printer is printed almost instantaneously.

Comment: I was observing render times over 500ms for some 6" labels and could create labels which took 2+ seconds to render (print times were fairly consistent).  These kinds of delays were [not acceptable](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eljo9CpEyzU)

Comment: How do you know these were render times and not some delay by e.g. the spooler API?